# Bootstrap framework column not working in tab-content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to include col-md-4 in content-tab but that not working image or text not hide if i click next tab. My target is Ihover plugins in 3 column but if i click next tab previous not hide

```
<ul class="nav nav-pils nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#webdesign">test1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#loga">test2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dtp">test3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#android">test4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="webdesign" class="section">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="loga" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div id="dtp" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="android" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the code with correct indentation, but I think the structure may now be incorrect. If this is the case, can you post the correct HTML please?

Comment: It should be `nav-pills` too, but you can't make a 1-char edit ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't working because Bootstrap columns must be a child of an element with the row class.  Try this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#webdesign">test1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#loga">test2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dtp">test3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#android">test4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="webdesign" class="section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="loga" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div id="dtp" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="android" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is key; It must be a DIRECT child of a row;   No grand-parents rows or older.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because loga, dtp and android tabs are child of webdesign tab. Hence, webdesign tab will display on default.

Try this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pils nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#webdesign">test1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#loga">test2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dtp">test3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#android">test4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="webdesign" class="section">
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1>fbbvasvba</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loga" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div id="dtp" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="android" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This markup needed considerable cleanup, it's always a great idea to refer to the Bootstrap documentation [for tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) and [nav pills](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills) when you hit problems. Here's the code you need:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#webdesign">test1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#loga">test2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dtp">test3</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#android">test4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="webdesign">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>col1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>col2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>col3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="loga">
    tab loga
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="dtp">
    tab dtp
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="android">
    tab android
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure I'd mix and match between `nav-pills` and `nav-tabs`, but that's your prerogative.

Answer (score 0):

**TL&DR**: When using a col-* you need to make sure it has a parent that is a div class="row". The rational is a row establishes a complete boundary (end-to-end) and a col-* breaks that boundry into 'columns'/'sections'.

**Solutions**: Is provided by the accepted answer; This provides additional justification.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="webdesign">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>col1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>col2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>col3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```